# I am contributing to an repository but " fatal: will not add file alias " is been shown while commit

Tags: git, github

As the problem is while commit,

fatal: will not add file alias 'src/Components/Button.js' ('src/components/Button.js' already exists in index)

The above error shows up, as haven't even opened the file and is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read the text *carefully and closely:*

> fatal: will not add file alias 'src/Components/Button.js' ('src/components/Button.js' already exists in index)

(note: I had to retype this, because you used an image instead of cutting-and-pasting text; please read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page).

Perhaps this might help:

```
src/Components/Button.js
src/components/Button.js
```

Can you see the difference between two letter `c`-s here?  One is UPPERCASE and one is <sub><sup>lowercase</sup></sub>.

- To *Git*, these are *two different file names*.
- To *your operating system*, these are *the same file name*.

Git can easily store both files.  But if you make it do that, you won't be able to *work with this repository any more*—or at least, not in a sensible way, with this particular commit.  Git is carefully keeping you from [shooting yourself in the foot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/shoot-yourself-in-the-foot).

Because *your* system doesn't distinguish between uppercase and lowercase in file and folder names, but Git does, you must be particularly careful when working with a repository that uses MixedCapItALIzaTIOn in file names for whatever crazy reason.  You should do one or more of the following before proceeding:

- Switch to a system that *does* think these are different file names.  The problem is now gone: Git and your OS agree that `src/Components/Button.js` and `src/components/Button.js` are two completely different files, and it's easy to store and work with both.
- Figure out why, despite Git's thinking that files should be named `src/Components/*`, your actual checkout has them as `src/components/*`.  Perhaps you should rename your `components` folder to `Components`.
- Dedicate yourself to stamping out this particular craziness: why do we have uppercase and lowercase in the first place?  Invent a time machine, go back in time to the invention of alphabets, and make sure the mistake never happens in the first place.
- Convert your software so that everything everywhere always uses lowercase whenever possible, so that the problem never occurs.  (YOU COULD USE ALL UPPERCASE, BUT THIS FEELS VERY SHOUTY.)

This whole area of file name craziness in certain OSes is a minefield.  Watch out!